# Hibernate custom sql query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am trying to execute below report mysql query through hibernate, I couldnt succeeded with hibernate Restrictions and Projections options.

```
SELECT sum(totalprice) as totalprice, hour(createdate) as createdate where day(createdate) = day(curdate()) group by day(createdate), hour(createdate)
```

Can anybody help me to convert this sql query into hibernate format?. Or is there any better an option available to execute these kind of complex sql queries?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you go for stored procedure which ease your implementation in case of hibernate call?